# Python process never finishing when called from Java

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, pytorch

I've tried to setup an AI with PyTorch. Everything is fine when I call my script from the console. But when I call the script in a Java `ProcessBuildera, it will finish but never terminate...

Here is the ProcessBuilder code

```
String[] cmd = {"python3", "-i" , "AI/Home-System.py",
                data.getName().replace(".csv", ""),
                "true",
                "false"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Hope that you can help me

**Edit:**

I found another solution. I call this script in a linux screen with

```
String[] cmd = {"screen", "-dmS", "AI-" + device,
                "python3", "AI/Home-System.py",
                data.getName().replace(".csv", ""),
                "true",
                "false"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Answer (score 2):

Read  the process' output stream, as the end of this stream allows your `ProcessBuilder` to exit. Or else call the `ProcessBuilder`'s `inheritIO()`.

Then `waitFor()` the process.

Here is some [sample code](https://mkyong.com/java/java-processbuilder-examples/) showing these steps.